# How do I write a recursive function that checks for certain characters in a string?

Tags: python

So I have this problem where I need to write a recursive function that checks for certain characters in a string and return them in a certain order. Basically it's supposed to split a string in two parts, the first part should contain lowercase letter, "_" and ".", the second part should contain uppercase letter, " " and "|". It should ignore all other characters.

Here's my code, my knowledge of recursion on strings is really bad:

```
def split(n):
    if len(n) <= 1:
        return n
    elif (n[0].isalpha() and n[0].lower() == n or "_" == n[0] or "." == n[0]):
        return n[0] + split(n[1:])
    elif (n[0].isalpha() and n[0].upper() == n) or n[0] == " " or n[0] == "|":
        return n
    else:
        return n[0] + split(n[1:])
```

So for example if I write `split("'lMiED)teD5E,_hLAe;Nm,0@Dli&Eg ,#4aI?rN@T§&e7#4E #<(S0A?<)NT8<0'"))`

It's supposed to return `('lite_hemligare', 'MEDDELANDE INTE SANT')`

Comment: Do you really need it to be recursive? You can solve this very easily with `re`gular expressions.

Comment: I don't understand why it has to be recursive, it clearly doesn't need to be.

Comment: I have made an iterative function of the same problem but I would want to make a recursive one as well

Comment: @Lukas again, why bother with this *at all*? Python has very nice regexes...

Comment: How about splitting the string recursively into 2 till you have just a single character left. Then inspect the character and based on your conditions. ?
However using RegEx, find or even iterations are more suitable for this probem then recursion

Comment: Was coding something for you, can't post as an answer, see :
https://0bin.net/paste/P-5LXf85hPjPeK90#9FV6ItIQVVM9npmNoOg7Dv+7a1AAkArqVRMCrPgO5Zp
This is not recursive but maybe you can pick some elements.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO it's easier if you make the function return a tuple with 2 strings always. Then you can just append to the first or second string of the tuple depending on which rule is triggered. In effect, the function could look like:

```
def separate(p, idx=0):
    if idx == len(p):
        return '', ''

    l1, l2 = separate(p, idx + 1)

    item = p[idx]

    if (item.isalpha() and item.lower() == item) or "_" == item or "." == item:
        l1 = item + l1
    elif (item[0].isalpha() and item[0].upper() == item) or item[0] == " " or item[0] == "|":
        l2 = item + l2
    return l1, l2
```

This way, the result is exactly what you look for.